# Gradle- is it possible to execute checks before initialization?

Tags: java, gradle

If have a multi-project setup in Gradle, and I'm dependent on two neighboring projects in the workspace `ChildA` and `ChildB`, and have them defined in the `settings.gradle` file as shown

```
include '..:ChildA','..:ChildB'
```

And I have the `build.gradle` defined below

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':..:ChildA')
    compile project(':..:ChildB')
}
```

Is it at all possible to check existence for the `ChildA` and `ChildB` projects before initialization occurs? If not, I'd like to execute actions to put them there (eg pull them from GIT, ask user to provide them, etc).

Is it possible to accomplish this or is it impossible to append checks before initialization?

Comment: It can be probably done in `settings,gradle` which is a normal gradle script. Here you can find a bunch of useful methods: http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html

Comment: This gave me a strong lead, very close to a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Thanks for the hint on the Settings documentation Opal.

Here is my new `settings.gradle` file. I declared my child projects in an array, and looped through them to see if they existed as sibling directories. If it does not exist, action can be taken to make it exist.

```
def projectNames = ["ChildA","ChildB"]

projectNames.each { name ->
  if (new File("../$name/").exists()) {
    println "project $name is present"
  } else {
    println "project $name is not present"
    //do something about it
  }
  include ":..:$name"
}
```